# PushBot Android client not working

Tags: android, push-notification

I followed the instruction but when I test sending the message I do not receive anything.

There are no errors in the application and the pushbot console sees that that there is a registered device.

How can I find out what is going on ?

The Code is very template like and follows all instructions that they have provided.

The application

```
import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {



        super.onCreate();
        String SENDER_ID = "ID here";
        String PUSHBOTS_APPLICATION_ID = "Pushbot App Id";
        Pushbots.init(this, SENDER_ID,PUSHBOTS_APPLICATION_ID);
     }
 }
```

The manifest looks like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.zuppush"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<permission android:name="com.example.zuppush.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.zuppush.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />




    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


      <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:name="com.example.zuppush.MyApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.zuppush.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.zuppush.MESSAGE" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>


        <activity android:name="com.pushbots.push.PBMsg"/>
<activity android:name="com.pushbots.push.PBListener"/>
<receiver
android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.example.zuppush" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.pushbots.push.MsgReceiver" />
<service android:name="com.pushbots.push.GCMIntentService" />
<service android:name="org.openudid.OpenUDID_service" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="org.openudid.GETUDID" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of `com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver` you are using, but if it's the default implementation taken from the old client GCM library, this implementation expects the `GCMIntentService` to be in the main package of your app (`com.example.zuppush`), which is not the case.

Comment: Well this is pushbot service which wraps around GCM. But I think this is a bug with pushbot. I have not changed any of this code but after crearting new project then I eventually got it to work again.

Answer (score 0):

I just signed up for pushbots recently. No technical support. No one is answering the phone. Their phone number forwards to a business that has nothing to do with pushbots. Please be aware, I don't think this company exists anymore. I lost my 1st month subscription to the service, without any service actually being delivered. I assume that pushbots service is no longer available, and that no one is still using the service, despite the fact that they are still accepting credit cards on their web site. Sketchy.